# Level of confidence in review queues

Tags: support, review-audit

In review queues sometimes *Review audits* appear to check if one pays attention. Is it a permanent feature or there exist some level of reviewer's authority (as for example Trusted User may suggest) above which these strange posts are removed?

Comment: Yes. This is permanent. We are all subject to these tests.

Comment: They can be annoying. A little bit. I appreciate choosing a less ranty title than the one above.

Comment: @Behaviour Please feel free to improve the title. I may not catch such subtleties...

Comment: The title of your question is fine; I was amused by the appearance of the title in the above comment, which was added automatically with my vote.

Comment: I've failed about 50% of the my recent audits. I stand by almost all of my decisions on those audits. Shame on the SE developers for imposing unwanted, pointy-haired features on our site, but until they cause me to lose reviewer privileges I don't really care.